# OSX Mavericks horizontal scrolling doesn't work well in Finder?

Tags: finder, trackpad, macos

I've noticed since updating to Mavericks last week (though this is a new Macbook, and I've been on Snow Leopard forever so not sure if this is 10.9 or 10.8 or what....) that horizontal scrolling in the Finder via two-finger trackpad movements is not working well.

I've tried turning inertia on and off, no difference.  Toggled everything in Trackpad in System Prefs, still no difference.  It seems "sticky" -- if I move my fingers continuously, the Finder scrolls in tiny fits and starts, but if i swipe, I get a normal inertia scroll.

Horizontal scroll works fine in Safari and Chrome, and in other programs; only Finder gives me trouble. Vertical scroll is fine in all contexts.

Has anyone else experienced this? I'm not having much luck Googling this, and wanted to check in here before posting as a bug / calling in a support ticket.

Comment: I see no problem with my 2012 MBA and mavericks.  Do you have any third party software that might plug into finder or receive mouse input (BetterTouchTool, for instance)?

Comment: I never noticed it, but I'm seeing the exact same thing on my 2012 retina MacBook Pro. A quick swipe/flick is fine, but continual scrolling is very choppy.

Comment: no third party software of that sort (no Finder/OS enhancements, etc.) based on the few votes maybe i should log this as a bug...

Comment: Posted here: http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html Though Apple doesn't provide public transparency into bug reports, so don't think there's a way to "vote" it up...

Comment: tried on my mid 2012 MacbookPro with Retina... See what you mean.  looks like it is confused with slight vertical movements while doing slow horizontal swipe.

But agree with you - it looks sloppy

Comment: @Joop you're right -- if you two-finger scroll perfectly horizontally it performs well. Wish I could add that to my bug report...but I don't have any way to get back to it :(

Comment: I notice this too, on a Mac Pro with Magic Trackpad running Mavericks.  The same problem applies in DaVinci Resolve.

Comment: I only see this when using column view, while I am trying to scroll the selected file out of the viewport.  For instance if a file in the rightmost column is selected and I attempt to scorll sideways such that that file becomes not visible.  Scrolling is smooth in all other finder views.  (2009, 2011, and 2012 MacBook Pro, 2012 Mac-Mini)

Comment: exact same problem - MacBook Pro late 2009with the 2,26 GHz processor

Comment: To expand on this symptom, I'm finding that if 2 finder windows are open, horizontal scrolling in one can cause both to choppily scroll sideways. Looks like the Finder window isn't properly capturing the event.

Answer (score 1):

No. Horizontal scrolling is butter smooth in Finder for several of my machines. I've tried several different resolution settings on the Retina MBP as well as tried mouse and trackpad scrolling on older machines with less CPU / GPU power than the 13 inch MacBook Pro.

None lag in any manner scrolling horizontally as opposed to vertically in my experience. Due to the voting on this question, perhaps there are some issues for certain configurations or something else that I'm doing differently than you, but even for all different views (icon, list, hierarchical, etc...) and finder windows with a thousand files in the folder, I'm not able to see slowness when scrolling horizontally.

Comment: Hm. I think @Joop's comment is right on for what I'm seeing -- if the trackpad movement is picked up as having a vertical component it kills the horizontal scroll. Do you have any sort of vertical two-finger scroll suppression?

Comment: I'll try a diagonal scroll to see, but no - I have stock software and hardware.